# getSupportMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity with SlidingMenu + ABS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am using Sliding Menu + ActionBarSherlock and for some "strange" reason I am getting this error. I get similar errors for "onCreateOptionsMenu" and "onOptionsItemSelected". I thought that importing Menu, MenuInflater and MenuItem from ABS would have solved the issues, but still I can't find the solution.

There shouldn't be any problem related to the dependencies between my project, ABS and SlidingMenu. Further I have extended all the classes correctly. Do you guys have any advice? Thanks.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    private Fragment mMapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

        getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mMapFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
             mMapFragment = new RunMapFragment();
             fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, mMapFragment)
                .commit();
        }
        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                getSlidingMenu().showMenu();
                return true;
            case R.id.button2:
                getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu();;
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SlidingMenuActivity` [appears to inherit from `FragmentActivity`](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingFragmentActivity.java), not `SherlockFragmentActivity`, and so you do not have ActionBarSherlock support, such as `getSupportMenuInflater()`.

You may have to clone `SlidingMenuActivity` and create `SherlockSlidingMenuActivity`, changing it to inherit from `SherlockFragmentActivity`, then use your `SherlockSlidingMenuActivity` as the base class for your `MainActivity`.

Comment: My SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity. I have also set a dependency between them, so what's wrong with that?

Comment: That's why to install ABS with Sliding Menu, this step is required: "Go into the SlidingActivities that you plan on using make them extend Sherlock___Activity instead of ___Activity."

Comment: @EdoardoMoreni: "My SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity" -- you do not have a `SlidingFragmentActivity`. You are importing `com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity`, which [appears to inherit from `FragmentActivity`](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingFragmentActivity.java).